# For each item, find COUNT of item with lower price

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Items(ID, Name, Price).

For every item in Items, I‘d like to receive an output of the form: (ID, Name, Count), where Count is the number of items in Items which are cheaper in price.

I have tried running a subquery with the same table but found no solution. It seems so simple, but I‘m a bit stuck.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you share the table definition, some sample data and expected result? Also please share your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Price, COUNT(t2.id)
FROM Items t1
LEFT JOIN Items t2 ON t1.price > t2.price
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Price
```

I add `Price` column to the output because you have not told that the presence of the same item name with different prices is not possible.